# Google Apps Script not triggering on edit

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have written a script to sort and pull entries from a sheets column and push to a Google Form ddl. This is functional, however the triggers I set in the apps script ide to run the function on edit and on change do nothing when either event occurs in the data. The only trigger that works is the on form submit, but this will not push new entries that are submitted to the form until the next submission. The script will run immediately and the data that populates the form will not included because fed by another sheet (for data validation) that is fed from the form data (this transfer takes a few minutes). I will share my code below for reference. Thanks for any help you can provide!

```
function popFormList() {


  Utilities.sleep(5000);

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID').getSheetByName("SHEET1");
  var form = FormApp.openById('ID');

  siteSort(sheet);

  var siteValues = sheet.getRange(2, 3, sheet.getLastRow()-1)
   .getValues()
   .filter(function(siteElement, sitePos, siteArr) {
    return siteArr.indexOf(siteElement) === sitePos;
   });
  var siteItem = form.getItems(FormApp.ItemType.LIST)
  .filter(function(siteItem) {
          return siteItem.getTitle() === "Title";
          })[0].asListItem();
  siteItem.setChoiceValues(siteValues);
  endSort(sheet);
}

    function siteSort(e) {
  e.getRange(1, 1, e.getMaxRows(), e.getMaxColumns()).createFilter();
  e.getRange('C1').activate();
  e.getFilter().sort(3, true);
}

    function endSort(e) {
  e.getRange('B1').activate();
  e.getFilter().sort(2, true);
  e.getFilter().remove();
}
```

Comment: It's not clear from your code which function is related to what trigger. However, what I can tell you is that `e.getRange('B1').activate();` is not going to work as `e` is not a sheet. [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

Comment: Hello,
The popFormList() is the specific function being triggered and I'm using simple triggers in the ui to do this. I want to run on spreadsheet edit however, the only time it work on trigger is when I select all the options (on edit, on change, form submit, on open) The script runs when executed manually, the sheet object is being passed from popFormList => siteSort => endSort.

Comment: What's with the `sleep` call? If you want to be sure calculations and writes are done, use `SpreadsheetApp.flush()`. Why no logging messages? Use `console` to send logs to Stackdriver so you can verify things are running. Note that simple triggers cannot be used since you are doing things that require authorization (opening remote sheets, forms). Note that all triggers are user-driven - they don't activate in response to programmatic changes or edits.

Comment: I see, well I'm programmatically transferring data from sheet to sheet so this makes since. I am curious how to implement the suggested functions if you can provide an examples? In this case how should I go about creating triggers for events that occur programmatically? The sleep function was to allow time for the scripts to transfer data before sorting and pushing the column to the form ddl.

Comment: Which is the function that is being called by the trigger? How are the changes being made to the spreadsheet that are supposed to activate the trigger?